# Function's analytic continuation is its own derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

This is the question we were asked at the university by our professor for complex analysis. Not as an exam, but as a challenge. I don't think he knew the answer himself.

Find a *nontrivial* example of a function $f$ defined on a neighbourhood of $z\in \Bbb C$ and a path from $z$ to $z$ so that the *analytic continuation* of $f$ along the path is $f'$.

It's easy to find trivial example: $e^x$. What I want is $f\ne f'$.

A variation to this problem, but much easier, is to find $f$ whose analytic continuation is $f+a$, $af$, or $-f$ (for some $a\in \Bbb C$).

> They are a logarithm, a power and a square root.

But the question in title I never knew how to tackle. Can anyone shed some light on it, please?

Comment: If the path is say $\gamma(t),$ does the requirement mean that at each $t$ we have $h(t)=f'(t),$ where $h$ is continuation of $f$ along $\gamma(t)$, or does this only need to hold at the endpoint of $\gamma$ (i.e. on the return to $z$)?

Comment: I'm asking just for the endpoint: $f$ and its continuation along the path are both defined in a neighbourhood of $z$; that's where the latter must be a derivative of the former. Of course, as a consequence, if you follow the path again, you end up having a function and its derivative on every point of the path (or in the neighbourhood of every point) and end up with $f''$ at $z$.

Comment: If as this comment starts you only want the continuation to match the derivative at the endpoint $z$ then consider $f(z)=z^2$ in a neighborhood of zero. Then the continuation of $f$ is itself, and its derivative at zero is $0$, matching $f'(0)=0.$ But in the rest of the comment you seem to say the opposite, that at each point of the path the continuation matches the derivative... So I don't (yet) see which you mean, that is, your last comment seems to start with one version and continue with the stronger condition along the whole path.

Comment: I said in a **neighbourhood** of $z$, not just matching the value at $z$ like $z^2$. Sorry I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: How do we know that following along the path again will yield $f''$?

Comment: One can rewrite the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form, and then remove the constraint that the solution be $2\pi$-periodic as a function of $\theta$. Then one can rewrite the derivative $f'$ in polar form and set it equal to $f$ evaluated at the angle $\theta+2\pi$. If we suppose the contour is the unit circle and $r\approx1$ we can suppose the real and imaginary parts are analytic in the variable $s:=r-1$ whose coefficients $u_n$ and $v_n$ are functions of $\theta$. Plugging the expansions into the polar forms discussed, we arrive at an infinite system of delay differential equations.

Comment: Thus we have $\displaystyle u(s,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n(\theta)s^n$ and $\displaystyle v(s,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty v_n(\theta)s^n$ subject to the CR equations: $$\begin{bmatrix}u_{n+1} \\ v_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(-n+\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \right)\begin{bmatrix}u_n\\v_n\end{bmatrix}$$ and the $f\to f'$ condition: $$\begin{bmatrix}u_n(\theta+2\pi)\\ v_n(\theta+2\pi)\end{bmatrix}=(n+1)\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_{n+1}\\ v_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I am not familiar with delay DEs, let alone systems of them. Perhaps we can assume $u_n,v_n$ are analytic in $\theta$, or else invoke Fourier theory (since the FT plays nice with argument shifts and derivatives).

Comment: @whacka About $f''$: If $g$ is analytic continuation of $f$ (along some path from $z_0$ to $z_1$, then $g'$ is analytic continuation of $f'$ along the same path, right? Now just take the function $f$ I'm seeking, the path from $z$ to $z$ that makes $f$ into $f'$, and let $g$ be $f'$.

Comment: I've just noticed the answer has been deleted. Although it didn't actually answer the question, it certainly demonstrated an idea how it could be tackled and therefore I think it should be kept. (I had +1'd it.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a positive answer, but an observation about the sort of analytic continuation which would satisfy your challenge problem.  If $f$ has the desired property, then it has that property all the way around the path $\gamma$.  That is, at any point on $\gamma$, if we continue $f$ one full time around $\gamma$ we obtain the derivative.  Following is justification (it was not immediately obvious to me, though it may be to you).

First some notation.

Let $\gamma$ denote the path in question, assumed to be parameterized with domain $[0,1]$. Since $\gamma$ is closed, for $s\in[0,1]$, we can define $\gamma_s$ to be the concatenation of the restriction $\gamma|_{[s,1]}$ followed by $\gamma|_{[0,s]}$.  Using modular arithmetic (modulo $1$) we can think of $\gamma_s$ having domain $[s,s+1]$.

Let $f_s$ denote the analytic continuation of $f$ along the path $\gamma|_{[0,s]}$ (viewed as having for its domain a neighborhood of $\gamma(s)$).  We are assuming that ${f_0}'=f_1$.

Let $A\subset[0,1]$ be the subset such that $r\in A\Leftrightarrow$ the analytic continuation of $f_r$ along $\gamma_r$ is ${f_r}'$.  We are assuming that $A$ contains $0$ (and is thus non-empty).  It is immediate from the definition of analytic functions that $A$ is open.  It is also not hard to show that $A$ is closed (since if the points where two functions are equal have an accumulation point in their common domain, they are equal in their common domain).  Thus $A=[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you. And from that follows that after 2 cycles you get $f''$. Yes, I have made that observation pretty much immediately after I first looked at that challenge.